# How to resolve "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found"?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I renamed my "id" into "teams_id"

[image: Look at the picture]

Now when I update it shows me following error

[image: Look at the image]

I tried using the declare it in my model also but it did not work

[image]

Here is my update code:

```
{
     $this->validate(request(), [
        'coach' => 'required',
       'team' => "required|unique:teams,team,$id",
       'manager' => "required|unique:teams,manager,$id",
    ]);

    $team=Team::findorfail($id);

    $team->team = $request->input('team');
    $team->coach = $request->input('coach');
    $team->manager = $request->input('manager');

    $team->save();
    Toastr::success('Team info was updated','Success!');
    return redirect('/teams');

}
```

Comment: you have team_id  not id

Comment: please dont post images here, just code. You should take a look in the how to ask topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok i will not post images any more.....pls teel me how to solve this problem and ihave "teams_id"

Comment: i'am new here pls ignore if anything goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably on your validator

```
'team' => "required|unique:teams,team,$id",
```

Check the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique) and try and use

```
'team' => "required|unique:teams,team,$id,teams_id",
```

Comment: This would run the `unique` check on the ID instead of the `team` field and not ignore the current team. Just add the `,teams_id` at the end without deleting anything.

Comment: ooopsss ....you are right.this problem occurrs for validator...do you know how to solve it

Comment: wait let me try

Comment: Yes Thomas is correct, follow his comment, i edited the answer also

Answer (score 2):

It is failing validation. [The `unique` validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-unique) is checking against the `id` column. It doesn't use the model primary key. Instead, change your validation rules to the following:

```php
    $this->validate(request(), [
       'coach' => 'required',
       'team' => "required|unique:teams,team,$id,teams_id",
       'manager' => "required|unique:teams,manager,$id",
    ]);
```